# Give and remove roles with a bot, Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

How do I make a bot in Discord.py that will assign roles present in a `role.json` file, while using the same command to both remove and add the same role. For example, `?role <rolename>` will both add and remove a role, depending on if the user has the role assigned. I'm a bit confused on how to achieve this.

My current bot uses `?roleadd <rolename>` `?roleremove <rolename>`.

Comment: If you already have the role adding/removing logic, the only part missing is the check to see if the user has the role or not: `if discord.utils.get(ctx.message.author.roles, name=rolename): removerole; else: addrole`

Comment: The current bot is in JDA, I could try converting it manually maybe then add that string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure where your `role.json` file comes into play, but here's how I would implement such a command

```
@bot.command(name="role")
async def _role(ctx, role: discord.Role):
    if role in ctx.author.roles:
        await ctx.author.remove_roles(role)
    else:
        await ctx.author.add_roles(role)
```

This uses the `Role` [converter](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/commands.html#converters) to automatically resolve the `role` object from its name, id, or mention.

Comment: Thank you, the `roles.json` was just the array of roles the bot was approved to assign.

Comment: @UnaTripolla Once you have the `role`, you can check `role.name` or `role.id` against the contents of that `json` to determine if the bot can assign the role.

Answer (score 1):

This code basically just checks that if the command raiser is the owner of the server or not and then assigns the specified role to him.

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.is_owner()
async def role(ctx, role:discord.Role):
  """Add a role to someone"""
  user = ctx.message.mentions[0]
  await user.add_roles(role)
  await ctx.send(f"{user.name} has been assigned the role:{role.name}")
```

Let me break the code down:

```
@bot.command()
@commands.is_owner()
```

These are just plain function decorators. They are pretty much self-explanatory. But still let me tell.
`@bot.command()` just defines that it is a command.
`@commands.is_owner()` checks that the person who has raised that command is the owner.

`async def role(ctx, role:discord.Role):` > This line defines the function.

```py
user = ctx.message.mentions[0] #I don't know about this line.
await user.add_roles(role) #This line adds the roles to the user.
await ctx.send(f"{user.name} has been assigned the role:{role.name}") 
#It just sends a kind of notification that the role has been assigned
```

Comment: Please give some context to your answer and don't just post code. Why does this answer the question?