# How to assign roles in discord.py latest version?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I have been looking for this all day, and I can't seem to find a proper way of assigning roles to members. I tried a couple ways of assigning roles:

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def claimrank(ctx, role: discord.Role):
    user = ctx.message.author
    await user.add_roles(role='Rookie')
```

and:

```
@client.command()
async def claimrank(member):
    role = get(member.guild.roles, name="Rookie")
    await member.add_roles(role)
```

What's worse, is that with both of these attempts, I don't get any errors, but the code doesn't do anything.
Please help!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this from a post recently today. I'll write the code and look for the original post.

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def addrole(ctx):
    user = ctx.message.author 
    role = 'role' #change the role here
    try:
        await user.add_roles(discord.utils.get(user.guild.roles, name=role)) 
    except Exception as e:
        await ctx.send('Cannot assign role. Error: ' + str(e))
```

Found the original post by @Patrick Haugh: [Give and remove roles with a bot, Discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51858123/give-and-remove-roles-with-a-bot-discord-py)